# Trouble with Oracle LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle11g

In our program, we have a Many-To-Many relation between a table 'Person' and a table 'Phonem'. This is archieved by an join table, 'PersonPhon'.

Person:

```
PERSID 
NAME
FIRSTNAME
DATEOFBIRTH
TYPE
[...]
```

PersonPhon:

```
PEPHPERSID <-- references the person
PEPHPHONID <-- references the phonem
```

Phonem:

```
PHONID
PHONEM
```

Due to a bug, some recent Persons were persisted without a reference to their respective Phonem entries. To read them from the database, I created a statement:

```
select p.persid from    
Person p left outer join PersonPhon ph 
on p.persid = ph.pephpersid              
where p.type = 'natural'
```

This statement was meant to give me all Persons with no respective entry in PersonPhon, and, with test data (only Persons without PersonPhon-entries) this works well. However, the statement also selects Persons if they have PersonPhon-entries, so I guess my statement has an error, yet I cannot figure out whats wrong.

Edit:

Entries:

Person-Table

```
PERSID | NAME | FIRSTNAME | AGE | TYPE (other columns ommitted)
76257713 | Wilko | Roger| 30 | natural
76257714 | Martian | Marvin | 50 | natural
```

PersonPhon-Table

```
PEPHPERSID | PEPHPHONID
76257713 | 21000
76257713 | 26000
```

Phonem-Table

```
PHONID | PHONEM
21000 | 4875122
26000 | 7468112
most entries omitted (> 100000)
```

With the above data, the statement gives:

```
76257713 
76257713 
76257714
```

Which is **unexpected** behaviour. Expected would be just `76257714`.

If the PersonPhonem-Table is empty, it gives:

```
76257713 
76257714
```

Which **looks** like the expected behaviour, but seems to be misleading.

Comment: can you post your dataset and expected output?

Comment: I'd like to see the WHERE clause too.

Comment: added where clause and info to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to find rows in `person` that don't have an entry in another table, it sounds like you want a `not exists` rather than a `left outer join`.  You could do a `left outer join` and then have a `where` clause that looks to see that the left joined table's values are `null` but that is generally less readable.

My guess is that you want

```
SELECT *
  FROM person p
 WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1
                     FROM PersonPhon ph
                    WHERE p.persid = ph.pephpersid )
   AND <<your additional predicates>>
```